# Make TextView Selectable

Tags: android, textview

How can I make a `TextView` selectable? By this I do not mean that I want to make the text within the `TextView` to be selected. What I want is that when the user taps on the `TextView`, it enters the selected state, and when the user taps another `TextView` in the layout, it exits the selected state and enters the default state.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign an onClickListener to any view, and do whatever you want when it is clicked.

So bottom line:

```
findViewById(R.id.yourViewName).setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        //Do whatever you need to do here

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an instance of `TextView` which will be used to know the last clicked `TextView`:

```
private TextView lastClicked;
```

Then in the `onClickListener` method of your `TextView`s, you have to change your lastClicked `TextView` to the current one.

```
myTextView.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {  
    public void onClick(View v) {
        lastClicked = (TextView) v;
    }
});
```

This way, you can retrieve the selected `TextView` from the `lastClicked` variable.

Answer (score 0):

That already exists, it's not called selected, it's called focused. You can check if a `TextView` is focused by doing:

```
myTextView.isFocused()
```

And in an activity you can get the current focused view by doing

```
getCurrentFocus()
```